# How do I make a color legend in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a plot which looks like this:

[image]

I would like to add a color legend, preferably outside the graph itself.  So, for example, a legend with a red dot and, after it, a description of what each red point in the plot means.  Similarly for blue.

i.e.

(red dot) 'description'

(blue dot) 'description'

Is there a way to do this in gnuplot?

Comment: Yes, remove the parts from your script where you hide the legend (remove `unset key` or `plot ... notitle` or `plot title ''` or their abbreviated forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, set the key properly:

```
set key top right outside
```

Then add  **title** of to the plot command like this:

```
plot 'data1.txt' title 'description 1', 'data2.txt' title 'description 2'
```